# Android: How to determinate how long i touch the screen?

Tags: java, android, time, touch

for my app i want to determinate how long i touch the screen. I want use the function onTouchEvent, i don't want use some images or some buttons to do it. Some idea? Otherwise, if there isn't a way, with a buttons but not with a image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can catch the movement using `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` to start the timer and stop it when you catch `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
              //start timer
        } else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
             //end timer
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

ZouZou's answer is good, but here's another solution, without struggling with timers. If you have a `MotionEvent event` then you can use `getDownTime()` and `getEventTime()` methods. The difference between them will be the duration of the touch.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    final long time = (event.getEventTime() - event.getDownTime();
    return true;
}
```